# Upgrade to Wordpress 4.6.1 and now "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Tags: php, wordpress

I upgraded to Wordpress 4.6.1 and a calendar page that displayed data from a number of different post types, starting showing an error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/centkuti/public_html/wp-content/themes/central-square-theater/page-templates/page-calendar.php on line 117

This wasn't happening before the upgrade and I examined the code and it hasn't changed. Here are lines 115 to 120:

```
<?php
  $prepost = get_post_custom_values('pre_post_related_show', $row->post_id);
  foreach($prepost as $v)
  {
    //echo $v;
  }
?>
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that `$prepost` is an array, and not null or false, before trying to iterate through it.

Comment: It is likely that this issue always existed but the new install no longer suppresses that error level or is configured to show errors where it once suppressed them. Anyways, aynber's comment is correct.

Comment: What do you expect from a `foreach` with a commented-out body?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<?php
$prepost = get_post_custom_values('pre_post_related_show', $row->post_id);
if(is_array($prepost) && count($prepost)>0) {
  foreach($prepost as $v) {
    //echo $v;
  }
}
?>
```